# NSData returns nil when passing certain base64 strings

Tags: ios, cocoa, base64, nsdata

I use

```
[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:content options:0];
```

to load binary data that is passed over network, as a key of a JSON object. Sometimes it works, but in others it fails, like with [this string](https://gist.github.com/aledalgrande/0690830224e92c0c21ca).

This is a string created on the other end by `NSData` itself:

```
[data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
```

Is there any option I have to pass, and why is it returning nil? String has multiple of 4 length and no weird characters, so I don't see why it fails?

Comment: Provide a hex dump of an invalid Base64 string. Also try some online validators.

Comment: @zaph the string itself was linked, and I couldn't find any online validator, only decoders, which don't really tell you if the binary string they decoded was decoded right. Anyway, I found the answer, see below.

Comment: Well, if it will decode I would guess it is valid. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the docs again, specifically this part:

> The default implementation of this method will reject non-alphabet
>   characters, including line break characters. To support different
>   encodings and ignore non-alphabet characters, specify an options value
>   of NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters.

The fact that it rejects characters means that it will reject the whole string because of those characters apparently, because when I added `NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters` to the initializer options, it worked even with the mentioned string.

Comment: ;-) I am not a native English speaker, but sometimes the meaning of some sentences in the docs reaches the complexity of a driving license question...